# Align contents inside a div

Tags: html, css, text-align

I use css style text-align to align contents inside a container in HTML. This works fine while the content is text or the browser is IE. But otherwise it does not work.

Also as the name suggests it is used basically to align text. The align property has been deprecated long back.

Is there any other way to align contents in html?

Comment: Give us more info please? past the code which is not working in other browsers.

Comment: You should give an example of  your markup so people know what you're trying to do. Otherwise, your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

text-align aligns text and other inline content. It doesn't align block element children.

To do that, you want to give the element you want aligned a width, with ‘auto’ left and right margins. This is the standards-compliant way that works everywhere except IE5.x.

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">Hello</div>
```

For this to work in IE6, you need to make sure [Standards Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) is on by using a suitable DOCTYPE.

If you really need to support IE5/Quirks Mode, which these days you shouldn't really, it is possible to combine the two different approaches to centering:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left">Hello</div>
</div>
```

(Obviously, styles are best put inside a stylesheet, but the inline version is illustrative.)

Comment: If you don't know the div width, which is often the case, this solution works perfectly in all browsers: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

Comment: I used <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">Hello</div>

Answer (score 17):

```
<div class="content">Hello</div>

.content {
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sorry , Above code will align a div center with in the   parent content

Comment: IDK why is it named `text-align` when it aligns everything to the centre 

Answer (score 16):

Below are the methods which have always worked for me

1. **By using flex layout model**:

Set the display of the parent div to `display: flex;` and the you can align the child elements inside the div using the `justify-content: center;` (to align the items on main axis) and `align-items: center;` (to align the items on cross axis).

If you have more than one child element and want to control the way they are arranged (column/rows), then you can also add `flex-direction` property.

Working example:

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**2. (older method) Using position, margin properties and fixed size**

Working example:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this also:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper_1">
        <div id="container_1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
body { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }

#wrapper_1 { clear: left; float: left; position: relative; left: 50%; }

#container_1 { display: block; float: left; position: relative; right: 50%; }
```

As *Artem Russakovskii* mentioned also, read the original article by [Mattew James Taylor](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support) for full description.

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, I hate all the solutions I've seen so far, and I'll tell you why: They just don't seem to ever align it right...so here's what I usually do:

I know what pixel values each div and their respective margins hold...so I do the following.

I'll create a wrapper div that has an absolute position and a left value of 50%...so this div now starts in the middle of the screen, and then I subtract half of all the content of the div's width...and I get BEAUTIFULLY scaling content...and I think this works across all browsers, too. Try it for yourself (this example assumes all content on your site is wrapped in a div tag that uses this wrapper class and all content in it is 200px in width):

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add...you may also want to set width: 0px; on this wrapper div for some browsers to not show the scrollbars, and then you may use absolute positioning for all inner divs.

This also works AMAZING for vertically aligning your content as well using top: 50% and margin-top. Cheers!

Comment: But how does that work for responsive pages? This is the worst solution IMO :-(

Comment: @Zimano I’m assuming that for this colloquial term of responsive pages, you mean some type of scrollable content site? You can always show and hide divs at certain viewport or scrollbar positions using a bit of code and some simple math. Seems to work great for the people who upvoted

Comment: If you don't know for what screen sizes or orientations you will be developing, you aren't gonna be helped with having hardcoded pixel widths in both your CSS and HTML. If you're making a desktop site and can guarantee the resolution and aspect ratio and will not dynamically rescale, then this might provide a solution!

Comment: @Zimano It doesn’t have to be hardcoded. I was merely trying to demonstrate a solution that works well. You can simply scale the image and its CSS programmatically based on either the browser’s width or its height, whatever you please

Answer (score 3):

Here is a technique I use that has worked well:

```html
<div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap;">Something Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers talk about horizontal align.

For vertical aligning multiple content elements, take a look at this approach:

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 200px; height: 140px; padding: 10px 40px; border: solid 1px black;">
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph #1</p>
        <p>Paragraph #2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just another example using HTML and CSS:

```
<div style="width: Auto; margin: 0 auto;">Hello</div>
```

Comment: None of what you wrote is specific to ASP.NET. It is just HTML and inline CSS. Did you mean to write out a server control with properties?

Comment: Fixed. The answer now mentions the correct technologies.