# Align contents of a div in the center

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `width:100%;` since I want to fill out the parent container.
I also want to have the contents of the div in its center. I can not find a `horizontal-align:center` attribute for the divs. How can I configure the div so that its contents are in the center?
I.e if the div is this big:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
                    Enclosing tags here  
                    in the center  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align contents inside a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684634/align-contents-inside-a-div)

Comment: @dTDesign:The answer linked does not work for me. It works if I do: `width:100px;margin:auto` but not if I do `width:100px;margin:auto`

Comment: then the best would be to create a jsFiddle so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
div {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for fixed width

```
div.class_name {
width: XXpx;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Dynamic Height

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="inside">some content</div>
</div>


.container
{
 text-align: center;
}
.inside
{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

In HTML

```
<div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
```

That all you need for the CSS.

Comment: I want to make sure that I fill out the parent container.Turns out I can not use `width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Read about `margin: auto` trick:
http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Comment: With `width:100%` and `margin:auto` it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting:

> margin: auto

I'm not sure if it helps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.class {
margin:0 auto;
width: 800px /*as desired*/ ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign width to div that you will want locate to center then right and left margin should get 0 value

```
{
 width: 100px;
 margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you looking for: `padding:0 20%;` using a `%` helps auto adjust the padding depending on how wide the parent div is. You can change `20%` to your preferred number.

```
.div {
width:100%;
padding: 0 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try text-align:center; to make content of div in center.